# This kind of error ~. What is a subject? kind or error?

Tags: subjects

This kind of error, where results are always on one side of the real value, is called “bias.

I Wonder which one is a subject: kind or error

I think kind is a subject.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and clearest answer to this question is the subject is a noun phrase and the subject noun phrase is this sentence is "This kind of error"

You may parse the noun phrase "This kind of error" as consisting of a determiner "This", a noun: "kind" and a prepositional phrase "of error".

But the grammatical subject is the whole phrase.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I learned in school that a prepositional phsrase with "of" becomes "adverbial or adjective phrase". So in this case I thought "adjective phrase" which modifies "This kind" and of course "kind", which again becomes an ending subject.